# subset a vector and sort it

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm looking into using some C++ for simple parts of my R package using the `Rcpp` package. I'm a C++ novice (but keen to learn!). I've implemented a few simple cpp programs using the excellent `Rcpp` - in fact that package has motivated me to learn C++...

Anyway, I've got stuck with a simple problem, which if I can fix would help lots. I have a `NumericVector` I want to subset and then sort. The code below sorts the whole vector (and would also deal with NAs, which is what I need).

My question is, say I want to extract a part of this vector, sort and have it available for other processing - how can I do that? For example, for a vector of length 10, how do I extract and sort the elements 5:10?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RcppExport SEXP rollP(SEXP x) {
  NumericVector A(x); // the data  
  A = sort_unique(A);  
  return A;
}
```

which I call from R:

```
sourceCpp( "rollP.cpp")
rollP(10:1)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: do you want to split it in half? also do you want to do this an R based solution or via C++?

Comment: Well, I want to extract a contiguous range e.g. 2:7, 5:8 or whatever say, based on a supplied start/end index). I would continue processing in C++ and then return the answer to R.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are 3 variants:

```
include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rollP(NumericVector A, int start, int end) {
  NumericVector B(end-start+1) ;
  std::copy( A.begin() + start-1, A.begin() + end, B.begin() ) ;
  return B.sort() ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rollP2(NumericVector A, int start, int end) {
  NumericVector B( A.begin() + start-1, A.begin() + end ) ;
  return B.sort() ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rollP3(NumericVector A, int start, int end) {
  NumericVector B = A[seq(start-1, end-1)] ;
  return B.sort() ;
}
```

`start` and `end` are meant as 1-based indices, as if you were passing `A[start:end]` from `R`.

Comment: Great - that's very useful, thanks. One follow-up point, what if I wanted to sort the data only and not take unique values as well.

Comment: In the second solution, just call std::sort( B.begin(), B.end() ) and return B. We will add a sort sugar interface.

Comment: I edited the answer to add a call to the `NumericVector::sort` method

Comment: `std::partial_sort_copy` also can be used.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look into C++ indexing, iterators and the whole bit.  At a minimum, you need to change your interface (vector, fromInd, toInd) and figure out what you want to return.

One interpretation of your question would be to copy the subset from `[fromInd, toInd)` into a new vector, sort it and return it.  All that is standard C++ fare, and a good text like the excellent (and free!!) [C++ Annotations](http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/) will be of help.  It has a pretty strong STL section too.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I did suspect this would be pretty standard stuff - I'm having to feel around a bit for sure. I appreciate the information you have provided that will help me follow up my question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::slice`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/slice/) on a [`std::valarray`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/). But if you want to use `std::vector` specifically then you can use [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) to extract a portion of the vector and then use [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) to sort the extracted slice of the vector.

Comment: That is a correct 'C++ only' answer. And with Rcpp, you can also  instantiate a C++ vector (eg `std::vector<double>`) from a SEXP and proceed that way.

Comment: Nice. Will looking into supporting `std::slice` in `Rcpp`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this quite easily by using the [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) implementation that receives two iterators:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename SeqContainer>
SeqContainer slicesort(SeqContainer const& sq, size_t begin, size_t end) {
  auto const b = std::begin(sq)+begin;
  auto const e = std::begin(sq)+end;
  if (b <= std::end(sq) && e <= std::end(sq)) {
    SeqContainer copy(b,e);
    std::sort(copy.begin(),copy.end());
    return copy;
  }
  return SeqContainer();
}
```

Which can be invoked like

```
  std::vector<int> v = {3,1,7,3,6,-2,-8,-7,-1,-4,2,3,9};
  std::vector<int> v2 = slicesort(v,5,10);
```

Comment: Nice. But I would pass the `SeqContainer` as reference, first create the `SeqContainer` and then sort it

Comment: @RomainFrancois: I didn't do this intentionally to allow optimisation (if the function is inlined. The Container has to be copied anyway. However, if (end-begin)/sq.size() is small, your approach might still be better.

Comment: This will have undesired effect with Rcpp vectors (e.g NumericVector) because they are just proxy to an array of data and the copy constructor does not copy the elements, but the ref to the underlying data.

Comment: Well this is incalled for. It is implemented like this for a reason. We dont need that sort of sarcastic comments on SO.

Comment: @bitmask, you realise, of course, that @romainfrancois is the co-author of `Rcpp`? In which case I think a little bit more courtesy will go a long way.

Comment: @RomainFrancois: Sorry, perhaps my choice of words were not the most polite. I certainly did not wish to imply any individual *person* was stupid, but that *one particular piece of code* wasn't doing the brightest thing. My point was that a copy constructor should have the semantics of copying an object. If it doesn't it is simply not doing the right thing. --- Again, I didn't intend to be rude and apologise if I appeared to be.

Comment: The right thing to do depends on the context. If copy semantics were the universally bright thing to do then why would C++ allow us to do otherwise. If we needed a container with copy semantics, we would just use `std::vector`, we need something different, and for that, what we implemented is the right thing to do. It is very bright to haver an umbrella, but if it does not rain, then it is just a very useless thing to carry around ...

Comment: @RomainFrancois: True. Nobody said the copy construction of an object has to be an immediate verbatim copy. Perhaps you want to implement some copy on write mechanism to make copies fast. But if I *want* to pass something by reference I pass it by reference, not by value---so if I copy an object I want an independent copy. And if it is not meaningful to copy an object, hide the copy constructor all together. Note that I'm really not familiar with R, so these are some general points regarding containers. At any rate, I should probably modify this answer.